# how to import two same android app in eclipse .. ? either rename package name or what?

Tags: android

Me and my friend started building our first app on android. We started on one laptop and then copied project  to another laptop too. Now we started doing our part on android separately.
Now i have to combine the work in one app, So when I tried to import the other project to my workspace, it says "Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace"  I tried changing my package name too. But even after that, the same warning comes.  what to do?  thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up some sort of repository with version control, then both of you can check out code, work on it and check it back in.  The versioning system will keep track of everything, perform merges and flag conflicts for you.

Some info about [Revision Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)

And a list of various [software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software)

Comment: and how to do that.. i am a newbie.. can you explain

Comment: it means i have to under stand that "git" kind off stuff for this small change? sorry then.. am not gonna do that.. thanks anyways

Comment: I suggested it only because it sounded like you were going to continue working together, in which case it would keep being an issue.  For a one time thing, I agree, it's a bit much.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do version control, you can use a diff program to comnpare the two files and merge the differences.  Set it up to compare, make the changes to "your" copy, and you should be set to go.

I've used ExamDiff to great success before (they have a very usable free version).

And here's a list of [diff software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools).